# font installation on Linux texlive (server) installation

Tags: fonts, texlive, linux, mtpro

I am trying to install the mtpro2 font for texlive2014 following the commands listed http://pctex.com/kb/62.html

Everything is working smoothly until the last command:

**updmap-sys --enable Map mtpro2.map**

which gives me the following error message:

**exec: 30: updmap: not found**

I am not sure what is the cause of this error. The only posts I could find online regarding such error are fairly old and related with Texlive 2008...

I tried to install this font on a Windows PC and another Linux PC and everything worked fine. Would you have any insight or tip regarding this type of error message ?

Thanks,

Comment: `updmap-sys --enable Map=mtpro2.map` is the usual syntax. Is `PATH` set correctly? Note that I see the link suggests that syntax only for Windows. However, that's what I've always used and I've never used TL on Windows.

Comment: On a UNIX system (including my Linux box), error 30 is EROFS, Read-only file system. Do you have write permission on it? This may be wholly irrelevant, as I see a different error on Mac OS when I don't have write permission. The "not found" looks more like updmap isn't in the user's PATH.

Comment: @egreg Note that the OP is using TL 2014 which definitely provides these commands ;). Besides, the error is coming from the final line of `updmap-sys` which is just a 30-line wrapper around `updmap`. So the system clearly has `updmap-sys` and definitely ought to have `updmap` unless something fairly serious is wrong with the TeX Live installation.

Comment: @cfr Oh, sorry, I misinterpreted the post.

Comment: If I run `PATH=/usr/bin/ /usr/local/texlive/bin/updmap-sys --help`, I get `/usr/local/texlive/bin/updmap-sys: line 30: exec: updmap: not found` which further suggests to me that this is a problem with `PATH` or a more serious one with the installation of TL. If `updmap-sys` is being invoked without a full path, it would be odd that `updmap` is not also found. But if `updmap-sys` is being invoked with a full path specification, it is very possible that `updmap` might not be found. @AdamMaxwell I'm pretty sure `30` is the line number and not an error code.

Comment: Thanks for your responses. I did invoke (as root) updmap with a full path specification as the command was not known (not in the PATH) of my server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in the definition of PATH.

After updating the PATH, I was able to run the **updmap** command properly. It should be said that the code **30** was indeed related to a line number and not an error code as updmap is called on line **30** of **updmap-sys**.

Thanks !